# Does this algorithm terminate in finite time?

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to determine whether the following algorithm terminates:

```
int n;
int s;
s=3n;

while s>0
{
  if s is even
  {
    s=floor(n/4);
  }
  else
  {
    s=2s;
  }
}
```

So far, I have tried to see whether I can come up with a pattern for how the algorithm behaves for arbitrary n. But I haven't had any luck so far. I'm pretty stumped right now. Any ideas or suggestions as to how I show that this algorithm terminates?

Comment: You've looked at what it does for small $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  for what $s$ will the loop terminate the next time through?  You need $s=0$ at the end of the loop. How about trying it for $n=1$ through $8$?